# Prove the equalities

Tags: calculus, summation, harmonic-numbers

I have to fine the following equality

$ \sum^{n-1}_{m=0} \frac{1}{(n-m)p} = neH_n$

where $H_n = 1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + .... 1/n$

**My Solution:**

$ \sum^{n-1}_{m=0} \frac{1}{(n-m)p} = \frac{1}{n} + \frac{1}{n-1} + \frac{1}{n-2} + ... + \frac{1}{1} = \frac{1}{1} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + .. \frac{1}{n} = \sum^{n}_{m=1} \frac{1}{mp} $

$ \frac{1}{p}\sum^{n}_{m=1} \frac{1}{m}  = \frac{1}{p}H_n$

How can I proceed further to get $neH_n$

Comment: What's $p$? Where's the inequality?

Comment: $e = \frac{1}{np}$

Comment: p is a variable quantity. (actually probability of an event)

@reuns how come? Is there any reference for it?

Comment: That's what implies your equality... There is nothing else to say

Comment: I am sure that is not the case...$n$ and $p$ are both independent variables.

Comment: What is $e$? From what you wrote as $neH_n=\frac{1}{p}H_n$ I thought that $e=\frac{1}{np}$ You say it is not, then how can we help you if we know nothing about $e$?

Comment: $e$ is a simple mathematical constant. The value of $e$ is constant while $n$ and $p$ are varying, and independent terms.

Comment: OMG... extremely sorry I missed one subtle note somewhere in the text of the paper.... $p \approx 1/ne$ (where again e is the Euler's constant)...Thanks guys for your help

Should I delete the question or post this answer as a separate answer, since this is not a very complex problem or innovative solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OMG... extremely sorry I missed one subtle note somewhere in the text of the paper.... $p≈1/ne$ (where again e is the Euler's constant)...

Thanks guys for your help Should I delete the question or post this answer as a separate answer since this is not a very complex problem or innovative solution?